# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunne in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing **Spring Boot + Batch XML** based approach. While running the code I am getting below exceptions. As per company standards, we're using our own DataSource which is wrapper and has all the security to read password from the crypto valut.

Could anyone please guide what's going wrong here ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.mastercard.EdsjpaApplication.main(EdsjpaApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.getJobInstances(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:254) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:162) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

**CommonConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.XX")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@ImportResource({ "classpath:jobs/XXXX.xml"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.XXXX.repository"})
public class CommonConfig implements BatchConfigurer{
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    @Inject 
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        return jobRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        return jobExplorer;
    }

    /*private JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor( new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }*/

    /*protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setValidateTransactionState(false);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }*/

    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository){
        return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
    }

    @Bean   
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager){
        return new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IOException {
        OracleDataSource ds = null;
        XXXInfoFactory userInfoFactory = new XXXInfoFactory();
        XXUserInfo userInfo = userInfoFactory.getXXUserInfo(value);
        if (userInfo != null) {
            ds = getDataSource(userInfo, edsurl);
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(CommonConfig.class); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the entire stacktrace ?

Comment: @Jayesh - This is the entire stack trace. This is only what I can see although I have used logback.xml file

Comment: can you enable `--debug` and post the entire log from start to finish of your spring boot app?

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine - This is run with the --debug options only. I wonder I can see above logs only.

Comment: If you run with `--debug`, you should see more than this stacktrace. Your datasource may be null if `userInfo` is null. Are you sure your data source is not null?

Comment: Yes Data is not null